# Why are the eigenvalues of this matrix incorrect?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $$
\left[\begin{array}{llll}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$

[image]

This slide says they should be $i,-1, -i, 1$. However, in wolfram I am [getting](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%7D) $-1,-1,1,1$. Why is this the case? These should not be the eigenvalues.

Comment: Something else is wrong in the slide.  $\pmatrix{0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0}\pmatrix{x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4}=\pmatrix{x_3\\x_4\\x_1\\x_2}$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Is the slide wrong then?

Comment: Yes, I think the matrix should be $\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0}$

Comment: The “Working upwards” bullet is also wrong: $$x_1=\lambda x_4=\lambda^2x_3=\lambda^3x_2=\lambda^4x_\color{blue}{1},$$ but that’s besides the point.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner But woudn't it still be circulant because it has constant diagonals? And the entries of the eigenvalues should be related to the roots of unity?

Comment: @random_0620 note that the incorrect matrix in the slide is a block matrix of the form $\pmatrix{0&  I\\I&0}$ so it will have the same eigenvalues of $\pmatrix{0&  1\\1&0}$ which is a circulant matrix. Note that $1$ and $-1$ the square roots of $1$ so they are roots of unity.